# How to select distinct value

Tags: t-sql, unique, distinct

I need to select all supervisor records. Our HR employee table set up like below

| Firstname | Lastname | Email | Supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frank | Johns | fjohns | Taylor, Don |
| Pat | Hope | phope | Taylor, Don |
| Jen | Dow | jdow | Taylor, Don |
| Taylor | Don | tdon | Olson, Mike |
| Kim | Ronda | kronda | Olson, Mike |
| Rob | Smith | rsmith | Olson, Mike |
| Mike | Olson | molson | null |

The final result should be like this

| Firstname | Lastname | Email | Supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Taylor | Don | tdon | Olson, Mike |
| Mike | Olson | molson | null |

If I use Distinct on supervisor then it gives me a list of supervisor but not their info. Please help

Comment: do not store a list as a delimited string in a column. just don't do it

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I assume the transposed First / Last for Don Taylor is a typo).

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Firstname, d.Lastname, d.Email, d.Supervisor
FROM MyTable d
INNER JOIN MyTable sup ON sup.Supervisor = d.Lastname + ', ' + d.Firstname;
```

or

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Email, Supervisor
FROM MyTable
WHERE Lastname + ', ' + Firstname IN (
    SELECT Supervisor
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Supervisor IS NOT NULL
);
```